# Property does not exist on type 'never' in my ionic angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

This is my code. I am getting id of each coach, participant and explanation and putting them in array. It is working but the same time throws errors such as

Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.

In both functions 'id' and 'name' same error. In my chooseName function 'id' does not exist in starting from line 4 and 'name' in line 7

I would appreciate any help! The app is on

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.15
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.2.13
@angular/cli                  : 11.2.13
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0

```
      chooseName(event){
    console.log(event)
    this.challenge.coach_names = [];
    this.coaches.findIndex(x => x.id === event.detail.value[0])
    console.log(this.coaches[this.coaches.findIndex(x => x.id === event.detail.value[0])])
    for (var coach of event.detail.value) {
      console.log((this.coaches[this.coaches.findIndex(x => x.id === coach)]))
      this.challenge.coach_names.push(this.coaches[this.coaches.findIndex(x => x.id === coach)].name)
      }
      console.log(this.challenge.coach_names)
}

  chooseParticipant(event){
    console.log(event)
    this.challenge.participant_names = [];
    this.participants.findIndex(x => x.id === event.detail.value[0])
    console.log(this.participants[this.participants.findIndex(x => x.id === event.detail.value[0])])
    for (var participant of event.detail.value) {
      console.log((this.participants[this.participants.findIndex(x => x.id === participant)]))
      this.challenge.participant_names.push(this.participants[this.participants.findIndex(x => x.id === participant)].name)
      }
      console.log(this.challenge.participant_names)
}
```

Comment: What is the line that throw this error ? Is it an error during the build or runtime ?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'. in line this.participants.findIndex(x => x.id === event.detail.value[0])  Property 'id' does not exist on type 'name'. in this.challenge.participant_names.push(this.participants[this.participants.findIndex(x => x.id === participant)].name) Same for chooseName

Comment: Does the error appear during runtime ?

Comment: yes, it appeared during runtime. But now i have it even when not running

Comment: Items in the `coaches` array are not initialized correctly. Can you show how you populate this array ?

Comment: in my ts public coaches: []; when retrieving from object avatar: null
city: null
country: null
id: "8880-6f9-43c6-8041-2c47"
name: "Coach"
subtype: "employee"
type: "user"

Comment: Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding it in comments, it will be more readable. I haven't understand how you populate your `this.coaches` array. But I think the problem is there.